# If one of hub is damaged,will it cause others hub damage too?why can't i enable the rapid dual homing

Tags: switch, ethernet, network, hardware, topology

[image]

There is a multi-ring topology, combined with 8 Hubs and 2 switches, i want to ask two questions

**1.** If H3 is damaged,but the fiber is still ok, will H2 damage too in the future? i have thinking to explain the reason, but i don't know it is right or wrong.

Reason: because H3 is damaged,so H2 will keep sending messages,m1, to H3 ,but H2 needs to send lots of other messages to H3 in the future,so this situation will cause too many messages need to be sent by H2, and it will let H2 be crashed, is this thinking right?

**2.**
The hubs are JetNet 4006f ,and 4006f provide two redundancy technologies, rapid dual-homing and rapid super ring,and my friend tells me that i have to disable the  rapid dual-homing ,just like the picture below,my friend and i don't know why,does anyone know the reason?i have a thinking too,but i don't it is right or wrong.

Reason:rapid dual-homing and rapid super ring are both redundancy technology,so i have to choose one of them,that is,if i choose the rapid super ring as the version,i can't enable the rapid dual homing.

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "hubs" *JetNet 4006f* are actually switches as well. "Hub" most commonly refers to *repeater* hubs only.

> If H3 is damage,but the fiber is still ok,will H2 damage too in the future?

No. It is next to impossible for any switch to damage a neighbor switch, especially over fiber.

> because H3 is damaged,so H2 will keep sending message,m1, to H3

No. If H3 fails, the H2-H3 link is down and no more message are passed.

For your question about proprietary *rapid dual homing* vs *rapid super ring*: I can't find decent documentation at Korenix. There are standards/drafts *Ethernet Ring Protection Switching* (ERPS) by ITU-T and *Ethernet Automatic Protection Switching* (EAPS) by IETF/ExtremeNet but it's unclear whether Korenix relates to those.

Generally, you should consider using a tree instead of one or multiple rings. With dual core switches and dual uplinks for the access layer (which I guess the rings are for), you'd have redundant uplinks, a *redundant core*, and *absolutely no interference* between access switches. Also, you could use standard RSTP/MSTP for redundancy or possibly MC-LAG (proprietary, but core only).

Comment: If there are 30 switches,and 5 of them are damaged in the short time,what do you think the reason of this situation?

Comment: You're having an actual issue with serial failure? I'd venture to point at the power but it could also be a production issue (one more reason to stay vendor-independent).

Comment: yes,i am having an actual issue with serial failure in the short time,we have checked the power,and the power is ok,and i also think the reason is the production issue,but i  am not sure about that,and i hope my boss can accept this production issue

Comment: I'd generally rule out a domino effect and seriously talk to the vendor.

Comment: Environmental issues might be a concern as well. Heat, vibration, dust and magnetic fields are the most common causes outside of electrostatic discharge. Checking the power when everything is working won't help you learn much. You need to watch it when the equipment dies. That can be very hard to do unless you monitor your power via measurement at the breaker panels and/or PDU equipment.